# Batch file to uninstall a program across multiple OS using IF/ELSE for paths with spaces

Tags: batch-file

What I'm after is a batch file that works across all Microsoft OS from Server 2003 all the way up to Windows 10, to check if a path (with spaces) exists, and if it does, run a command to uninstall McAfee's Virusscan Agent.  The problem is the path changes per OS, but the command to uninstall the McAfee Agent remains the same.  Here's what I've got so far; I know it's probably completely wrong, but it'll give you a basic idea of what I'm after:

```
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\McAfee\Common Framework" (
c:
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\McAfee\Common Framework"
start /wait frminst.exe /forceuninstall /silent
) ELSE (
       IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\McAfee\Common Framework"
       c:
       cd "C:\Program Files\McAfee\Common Framework"
       start /wait frminst.exe /forceuninstall /silent
       )    ELSE (

                 IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\McAfee\Agent\x86"
                 c:
                 cd "C:\Program Files\McAfee\Agent\x86"
                 start /wait frminst.exe /forceuninstall /silent
                 )

shutdown /r /t 30
```

So basically, it should check for the existance of one of three default agent install paths (because the path changes on Server 2003/Windows7/Windows10) and if the path exists, go to that directory, and run the `frminst.exe` executable silently, then reboot the machine after 30s.

Comment: Saying "this is my first post..." does not help keeping things short, does it?

Comment: Would it not be easier to evaluate the computers' uninstall information instead of checking every possible installation location?